# AWS HSM (hardware security module) for SSL offload slow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, cloud, hsm

Just set up two EC2 Ubuntu 16.04 t2.medium instances, each with standard nginx from the Ubuntu repository. Set up also a HSM cluster in with one HSM in the same availability zone, so everything is in the same subnet.
One of the nginx instances I set up to use the AWS HSM and it looked fine.

Then tested HTTPS load with Apache Benchmark, like this:

```
ab -n 10000 -c 20 "https://certificate.domain/"
```

And I got really disappointed to see that the instance that uses HSM for the SSL operations is about 3x slower than the standard nginx instance that is using its local CPU only:

```
Requests per second:    80.48 [#/sec] (mean)
```

vs.

```
Requests per second:    231.24 [#/sec] (mean)
```

Any ideas why that could be? Is that a normal outcome?
Are these AWS HSMs supposed to be simply safe but not that fast?

Comment: Are these number flat over time or do they burst at the start and then dropoff (HSM numbers)?

Comment: @JohnHanley, performance seems pretty flat to me. I tried a few times with different number of concurrent connections, but the results and performance seems about the same

Comment: I use HSM but not for SSL offload. I don't have any answers but I have interest in following this thread. Keep this question updated if you have time.

Comment: @JohnHanley, I posted the same question in the AWS forums, let's see if I get any reply

Comment: Thank you. Hopefully good information from AWS will appear.

Comment: What's your ping latency?  Keep in mind that the primary use case for an HSM is security, not performance.  You are probably seeing what you can expect to get.  Maybe you get something faster if you are "closer" topologically to the data center the HSM is in, but that's random chance, not something you can take advantage of (short of moving to co-locate).

Comment: @rip..., it was in the same availability zone, ping is around 1-3ms

Comment: When you use the host CPU you are benefiting from a multi-core CPU.  When you are using an HSM, treat it like a single core CPU since every access is serialized.  A 3 to 1 reduction in throughput sounds reasonable, assuming a 4core CPU on the host.

Comment: It was 2 cpu cores, but I got your point. Anyway, My conclusion is that it’s not good value for money (for what I was trying to achieve)

Comment: In that case, use the HSM to store an AES-256 key.  Use that key as a wrapping key.  Wrap your nginx private key using the wrapping key. On start up of nginx, unwrap the private key, and then use that on the host's CPU.  Not as secure as holding the https key in the HSM, but at least the https key is secure while at rest.  Assuming nginx supports this algorithm, which dunno.  I do HSMs :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip @rip... it makes sense if my goal is security. My actual goal though is optimising performance, our front-end servers got too much of a load because of SSL and I was trying different solutions. One (above) was to "outsource" that to a HSM, but obviously that is not performing better :)

Comment: As i understand it with the cloudhsm openssl plugin for nginx, the hsm is only used for the initial pki verification, after that the normal session key is used between nginx and the browser.